# How to extract all entries in hierarchical order from ldap?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm using `ldapsearch` to move a whole subtree from an existing (Novell eDirectory) server to a new OpenLDAP installation, but it seems that tool is not extracting the entries in hierarchy order, such that `cn=man,ou=org,o=company` comes before `ou=org,o=company` in the output, breaking the following `ldapmodify -a`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is `ldapsearch` the right tool?

The origin server configuration can't be changed nor it can be stopped for a cold dump.

Comment: Common issue with few solutions. We found some at: http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDIF%20Sort%20Tools

Comment: @jwilleke I'll check those tools, thank you.